# C: Storing 1d character pointer arrays into a 2d character array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am facing problems with pointers in C. Mostly when we use pointers as arrays to store numbers or strings or characters.

My problem is, I have given `char **arr` to store string from `char *a` and `char *b`.

I am having trouble understanding how to take input in `char *a` and `char *b` from the user, and then storing these into the `char **arr` and printing them also from `arr`.

My code is below, but it is not working.

```
int main() 
{
   int n;
   scanf("%d", &n);

   char* a;
   char* b;
   a = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(char));

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      *(a + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
      scanf("%s", *(a + i));
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      *(b + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
      scanf("%s", *(b + i));
   }

  // How to store char* a and char* b in char** arr now.....
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your question. You need to ask a specific question. Your code to read the strings with `scanf` is broken because `*(a+i)` is a `char`, but `scanf` must be given a pointer. (`a` is `char *`, so `a+i` is another `char *`, adjusted by `i`, so `*(a+i)` is a `char`.) But once that is fixed, the code will read characters into memory (as long as the `scanf` works and there is no overflow of the buffers). Then you want to store the characters? But they are already stored in memory. So it is unclear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
char* a;
a = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(char)); 
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   *(a + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char)); /* Not required as you have allocated for a which is char pointer */
   scanf("%s", *(a + i));
}
```

first you are allocating memory for `a` which is single *character pointer*. And then allocating for `*(a+i)` i.e single `char` which is not required, default `1` byte is reserved for a character variable.

You need to change the type of `a` from `char*` to `char**` to achieve above. For e.g

```
char** a;
a = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(*a));
if(a == NULL) {
    /* @TODO proper error handling */
}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   *(a + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(**a)); /* allocating memory for a[i] */
   if(a[i] == NULL) {
       /* @TODO proper error handling */
   }
   scanf("%s", *(a + i)); /* store into each a[i] */
}
```

Same applicable with `b` as well. It should be of `char**` type to hold pointers into it. For e.g

```
char** b;
b = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(*b)); /* Always check the return value */
if(b == NULL) {
  /* @TODO proper error handling */
}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   *(b + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(**b)); /* allocating memory for b[i] which is a pointer */
   scanf("%s", *(b + i)); /* store user input into each b[i] */
   if(b[i] == NULL) {
        /* @TODO proper error handling */
   }
}
```

And once you are done with usage of dynamic memory, free the dynamically allocated memory by calling `free()` function.

Comment: My doubt is how to store single character pointers to a double character pointer . Basically my doubt is about syntax.How to write it in the form of code.

Comment: It's heresy to say so on SO, but (IMMHO) `malloc(1024 * sizeof(char))` is *much* more readable than `malloc(1024 * sizeof(**b))`.

Comment: @Kingsley - that's not correct. Using the dereferenced pointer to set *typesize* is the correct way to avoid errors. In the case of `sizeof(char)` it is superfluous to begin with as `sizeof(char)` is defined by the standard as `1`.